# Lenovo Ideapad Creator 5 won't charge the battery after I install Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: power-management, lenovo, laptop, battery

Lenovo Ideapad Creator 5 won't charge the battery after I installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS before that it has Windows 10 which I had to replace with Linux.

Another issue is that it has is the charging indicator light is always RED when it's plugged in it was WHITE before on Windows I mean.

Edit: I haven't had this issue on Windows, the battery got charged properly and goes to about 85-90% depending on battery temp for a better life span. but now on Ubuntu, it won't go up when it's plugged but when it's unplugged it will use the battery. I'm afraid if the level goes down to 0 what will happen..

How can I solve this?

Comment: Charging is generally not handled by the OS, but by the UEFI/BIOS. Has the battery been recently been replaced as well as the OS? 

Comment: @matigo No it is a brand new purchase, I never replace the battery.

Comment: Does Ubuntu report the battery level? What is the current charge? Many modern OSes will *ask* the hardware to not charge the battery endlessly. If the charge is higher than 85%, it may not be an issue. If it goes lower than this and the device is not charging despite being plugged in, then further avenues for investigation can be pursued ...

Comment: @matigo Yes right now it shows 56% in power settings, it says charging but it's not. if I unplug the power, the battery becomes less but if I plug it back it will stuck. also in Power Statistics, Time to full is 0

Comment: @matigo according to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/980490/lenovo-x1-thinkpad-battery-not-charging-in-17-04?rq=1 I tried to disable the battery in BIOS but there is no such option in Ideapad.